# Rails ActiveStorage versioning (with paper_trail or somthing like that)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage, paper-trail-gem

I have a User model, which has one image.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_paper_trail
  has_one_attached :image
end
```

I decided to paper_trail gem because I need versioning for User attributes.
However, I noticed that I don't know how to get versioning information for image.

```
  PaperTrail::Version.where(item_type: "User").first.object
=> "---\nemail:XXXX\n'\ncreated_at: 2021-10-28 13:06:15.206202000\nupdated_at: 2021-10-28 13:06:19.789124000\n"
```

Does anyone else know how to get previous version of ActiveStorage?
I'm using paper_trail gem, so it's the best if paper_trail can do it.

Comment: `has_one_attached` is an association. PaperTrail does not record association data. You can write custom [metadata](https://github.com/paper-trail-gem/paper_trail/#4c-storing-metadata), or you might try the [paper_trail-association_tracking](https://github.com/westonganger/paper_trail-association_tracking/issues) plugin.

Comment: You show me a very simple but excellent idea. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I'm a little late to the party, but I have found a need for version tracking on my ActiveStorage models.  Here's what worked for me:

1. Create a new file in `/config/initializers` called `active_storage.rb`
2. In the new `/config/initializers/active_storage.rb` file, add the following code:

```rb
Rails.application.config.to_prepare do
  ActiveStorage::Record.has_paper_trail
end
```

3. Reboot your Rails server

You should now see version tracking for all subclasses of `ActiveStorage::Record`.

Comment: Oh, the party is still on, Thanks! I will try it.